# Word 2010 Userform + VBA AutoTextEntry problems

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have around 60 pages of code that I have picked up and edited from another member of staff. What I have is a Userform where a person will enter some details to create a letter. This part is all good and working. The next part is where I am having troubles. Basically, if someone clicks a button then it will insert some autotext and fill in any bookmarks as necessary.

```
If chk1 = True Then
   ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("1").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bm1").Select
   Selection.Text = txt1.Value
End If

If chk2 = True Then
   ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("2").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

End If
Now what I am trying to figure out is how to change the selection/range to just below the insert. So when the autotext entry is input and after it has changed the bookmarks as required I would like the selection to be under it to start a new paragraph.

Example: Text text text text text text text

<- Selection will be here for entry of new autotext.

I have been looking online and I just don't know how to do it! I Should mention that this is sort of in the middle of the document. I have a signature and stuff below it so it doesn't really work with the make the selection the last paragraph sor of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know something like this, ask Word.

Put cursor where macro leaves it, Alt + T, M, R. Move by keyboard the cursor where you want it. Turn off recording (Alt + T, M, R). Copy and paste from the new macro into your macro.

---

These are some examples from doing the same thing in Excel.

You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.

Alt + T, M, R

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of this..... Always good to get another pair of eyes looking at things to pick out the silly things you missed! I did that all the time with excel macros... Okay well its working now so thank you so much!